# Set Gradle Cache Directory?

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to set the Gradle cache directory, without having to set the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable? I would like the Gradle cache to exist in the same workspace as my code, but it seems this is only possible with a bash script wrapped around Gradle.

To clarify, I'm talking about the Gradle cache that contains resolved dependency files.

Answer (score 7):

I think this might be useful to you - [Appendix D. Gradle Command Line](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html)

> ```
> --project-cache-dir
> ```
>
> Specifies the project-specific cache directory. Default value is
>   .gradle in the root project directory.
>
> ```
> --gradle-user-home
> ```
>
> Specifies the Gradle user home directory. The default is the .gradle
>   directory in the user's home directory

Snippet of it in action - just tested locally:

```
C:\dev\ws\NYSSIS-Intellij\ear>gradle --gradle-user-home c:\dev\cache-test build
Build initialized to use p12_2014_03_31e-windows-models.jar for ChoiceMaker model                                                                   
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE                                                                                              
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:web:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:web:compileGroovy                                                                  
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.6/groovy-all-2.4.6.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.15.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.2.15.RELEASE.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/3.2.15.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-3.2.15.RELEASE.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context-support/3.2.15.RELEASE/spring-context-support-3.2.15.RELEASE.pom
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It moved the project cache directory, but it did not change the home directory cache, where downloaded dependencies are stored.

Comment: I'm sorry --gradle-user-home
Specifies the Gradle user home directory. The default is the .gradle directory in the user's home directory.

Comment: @Eric - I just improved the answer with working example using --gradle-user-home

Comment: Okay, that did work. Thanks. However, I wish to set this somewhere that can be added to source control (i.e. gradle.properties). I tried adding systemProp.gradle.user.home=foo to my gradle.properties and it did not work.

Comment: @Eric ...  Try: `org.gradle.caching=true`.  As it says, the default will be the root project\.gradle.  That makes a bit of sense with a complex development environment; and I think I'm seeing caching to user home and in the root-project directory depending on what IDE or command I run.  Something INSIDE the project gradle.properties file to set the directory is my preference.

Comment: @Brian - I stumbled upon your answer here since I was trying to do the same. It didn't quite work for me - I get a `caches` directory created in my custom directory but it doesn't contain any downloaded dependencies. Maybe `--gradle-user-home` flag changed since?