# Jhipster gradle build failde

Tags: jhipster

When running jhipster from command line I get the following error, I am using jhipster latest version (v3.12.2) on windows machine. It seems there is an issue with gradle build.

```
gradlew.bat bootRun
:cleanResources
:bootBuildInfo
:bower
:nodeSetup SKIPPED
:gulpConstantDev
[15:59:03] Using gulpfile C:\dev\test\gulpfile.js
[15:59:03] Starting 'ngconstant:dev'...
[15:59:03] Finished 'ngconstant:dev' after 23 ms
                                                                                                                                           :processResources
:compileJava
:classes
:findMainClass
:pathingJar
:bootRun
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/Environment
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.Environment
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" :bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.498 secs
```

Using Maven works.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a gradle issue in this version, which produces this error if gradle cache path contains spaces. I suggest you permanently remove gradle cache to a path without spaces: [Set Gradle Cache Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575542/set-gradle-cache-directory)

If you need a temporary quick fix, like me, you can patch this using a dirty approach to fix the JHipster classpath. Suppose your Windows user name is "Your Name". Then it will be a part of the path string and you will need to replace it with "yourna~1" (it is the 8-chars equivalent for Windows long name directories, i.e. first 6 chars of the directory name lowercase without spaces + "~1"). You can patch it in your build.gradle, line 55 and the issue is gone:

```
        attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect {
            it.toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/').replace("Your Name", "yourna~1")
        }.join(' ')
```

Comment: Thanks, setting Gradle Cache Directory  as "gradlew.bat --gradle-user-home c:\dev\cache-test" did not work. But changing the build.gradle works.  Thx for help.