# Running Gradle to start a docker container that will mount the current directory and run Gradle

Tags: docker, gradle

I have my Gradle build running both locally on my Windows machine and inside of an Ubuntu Docker container.  It works nicely.  Then I tried to create a new Gradle target on my Windows host machine that would package up the docker container, then run it.  When it runs, it mounts my current project directory and then execute the tests.  That's when I ran into this exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type FileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry using TaskExecutionServices.createFileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry().
> Could not create service of type CachingFileHasher using TaskExecutionServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type FileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry using TaskExecutionServices.createFileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:798)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:752)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:589)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:634)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:762)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:751)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:589)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:634)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:762)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:751)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:589)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:634)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:429)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:410)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleScopeServices$3.create(GradleScopeServices.java:127)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleScopeServices$3.create(GradleScopeServices.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)

        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type CachingFileHasher using TaskExecutionServices.createFileSnapshotter().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:798)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:752)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:589)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:634)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:762)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:751)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:589)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:634)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getAll(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:657)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getAll(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:560)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeProvider.getAll(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1034)

        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CachingProvider.getAll(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:990)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getAll(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:404)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.TaskExecutionServices.createFileCollectionSnapshotterRegistry(TaskExecutionServices.java:172)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:462)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:796)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:89)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:73)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.incrementLockCount(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:94)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.acquireFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:136)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.onStartWork(DefaultCacheAccess.java:425)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:182)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:170)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:339)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:51)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.createCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:110)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.createCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:166)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskHistoryStore.createCache(DefaultTaskHistoryStore.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.<init>(CachingFileHasher.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.TaskExecutionServices.createFileSnapshotter(TaskExecutionServices.java:156)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:462)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:796)
        ... 83 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockStateAccess.readState(LockStateAccess.java:69)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockStateAccess.ensureLockState(LockStateAccess.java:46)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockFileAccess.ensureLockState(LockFileAccess.java:57)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:278)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:138)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:86)
        ... 100 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.124 secs
:testDocker FAILED
```

Oh no!  It looks like there are files in my `project/.gradle/` directory that my host has locked and that the gradle instance running on my docker container wants to lock too.  Any idea how I get around this, without making a copy of the whole source tree?  My source tree includes a massive node_modules directory that's very painful to copy to a temporary build directory.  I'd like to be able to run Gradle both on my machine and on my docker instance at the same time.

Can I change the project/.gradle directory possibly?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575542/set-gradle-cache-directory)?

Comment: Oh.  I found the gradle user directory, but not the project cache directory flag.  Nice!  Make it an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Did you check if it solves your particular problem of building the same project twice at one time? Please note, that you can use the `startParameter.projectCacheDir` property in your `settings.gradle`, too. Also, you may change your project build directory to avoid having problems with parallel access there.

Comment: Oh, no, it doesn't.  Well, not entirely.  It seems the files are also owned by root and I can't access anything.  See more here:  https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/39

Comment: But after I fixed that, and set `--project-cache-dir .gradleDocker` it seems to work, yes!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Gradle in WSL 1. I shared `~/.gradle` between Windows and WSL through a Linux symlink. That caused build failures in WSL. I can recover by `gradle --stop` both in Windows & WSL but it comes back. Just removed sharing of `~/.gradle` between WSL & Windows.

Of course private `--gradle-user-home` will solve the problem but for development is wasting of storage space.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4309 - [WSL2] Gradle build on Windows fail for project located on WSL filesystem due to filesystem lock issue.